# In MongoDB, which index would be more efficient? One that queries an array with two values, or one that uses an $or statement?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a document that looks like this:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("5260ca3a1606ed3e76bf3835"),
  event_id: "20131020_NFL_SF_TEN",
  team: {
    away: "SF",
    home: "TEN"
  }
}
```

I want to query for any game with "SF" as the away team or home team.  So I put an index on `team.away` and `team.home` and run an $or query to find all San Francisco games.

Another option:

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId("5260ca3a1606ed3e76bf3835"),
  event_id: "20131020_NFL_SF_TEN",
  team: [
    {
      name: "SF",
      loc: "AWAY"
    },
    {
      name: "TEN",
      loc: "HOME"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the array above, I could put an index on `team.name` instead of two indexes as before.  Then I would query `team.name` for any game with "SF" inside.

Which query would be more efficient?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you would want to use the second example you gave with the single index on `team.name`.

There are some special considerations that you need to know when working with the `$or` operator. Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) (with some additional formatting):

> When using indexes with `$or` queries, remember that each clause of an `$or` query will execute in parallel. These clauses can each use their own index.
>
> `db.inventory.find ( { $or: [ { price: 1.99 }, { sale: true } ] } )`
>
> For this query, you would create one index on price:`db.inventory.ensureIndex({ price: 1 }`,
>   and another index on sale:`db.inventory.ensureIndex({ sale: 1 } )`
>   rather than a compound index.

Taking your first example into consideration, it doesn't make much sense to index a field that you are not going to specifically query. When you say that you don't mind if `SF` is playing on an away or home game, you would **always** include both the `away` *and* `home` fields in your query, so you're using two indexes where all you need to query is one value - `SF`.

---

*It seems appropriate to mention at this stage that you should always consider the majority of your queries when thinking about the format of your documents. Think about the queries that you are planning to make most often and build your documents accordingly. It's always better to handle 80% of the cases as best you can rather than trying to solve all the possibilities (which might lead to worse performance overall).*

---

Looking at your second example, of nested documents, as you said, you would only need to use one index (saving valuable space on your server).

Some more relevant quotes from the [`$or` docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) (again with added formatting):

> Also, when using the `$or` operator with the `sort()` method in a query, **the query will not use the indexes on the `$or` fields.** Consider the following query which adds a `sort()` method to the above query:
>
> `db.inventory.find ({ $or: [{ price: 1.99 }, { sale: true }] }).sort({item:1})`
>
> This modified query **will not use the index on `price` nor the index on `sale`.**

So the question now is - are you planning to use the `sort()` function? If the answer is yes then you should be aware that your indexes might turn out to be useless! :(

---

The take-away from this is pretty much "it depends!". Consider the queries you plan to make, and consider what document structure and indexes will be most beneficial to **you** according to your usage projections.